# JFileChooser set Control Buttons Are Shown are false and 1

Tags: java, jfilechooser

I'm having difficulty getting the file back from a `JFileChooser` when `setControlButtonsAreShown()` is set to false.

If the user makes a selection of an exisiting file I can get this file with `getSelectedFile()`, but when they type in a new file name `getSelectedFile()` returns null.

When I use a `JFileChooser` with `setControlButtonsAreShown(true)` and I click on the Save button any filename the user has typed can be obtained with `getSelectedFile()` as expected, but when `setControlButtonsAreShown(false)` is used I just can't seem to get this file returned.

This happens even if I call `approveSelection()`, which supposedly does the same as clicking on the Save button if it had been show.

What am I doing wrong? Or any another way to assign `JfileChooser` open button action event to customized personal `Jbutton`?

Comment: Without the control buttons., how are you closing the file chooser? If you press enter after giving a file name it should work. If you close the window, it is considered as a cancel operation. Are you checking the return value from the `showSaveDialog` ?

Comment: I added this filechooser to the panel, and open and cancle button are custom button not file chooser button. It is not a saving file chooser, it is selecting file chooser.

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

This the workaround I came up with.
This will iterate through all the components inside `FileChooser` `Container` and get the text from the `JTextField` and set as selection in the `FileChooser`
Call this after some button click or any event.

```
    private void failProofSetPath(JFileChooser chooser) {
        File selectedFileFromTextBox = null;
        String text = getTextOfFileViewer(chooser);
        if (text != null && new File(text).exists()) {
            selectedFileFromTextBox = new File(text);
        }
        if (selectedFileFromTextBox != null
                && (chooser.getSelectedFile() == null
                || !selectedFileFromTextBox.equals(chooser.getSelectedFile()))) {
            chooser.setSelectedFile(selectedFileFromTextBox);
        }
    }

    private String getTextOfFileViewer(Container c) {
        int len = c.getComponentCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            Component comp = c.getComponent(i);
            if (comp instanceof JTextField) {
                JTextField b = (JTextField) comp;
                return b.getText();
            } else if (comp instanceof Container) {
                String val = getTextOfFileViewer((Container) comp);
                if (val != null) {
                    return val;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```